# Android Low memory on start

Tags: android, memory

For several apps that I have tested, it seems that the Heap memory usage is quite high even **at the start** of the application. For example, I have an app that is supposed to show an image from assets on an ImageView. But, even before loading the image, used Heap, is about 95%. When I load and display the image, it still fine, it increases used memory to about 98%. But, if I create a copy of the bitmap, then app crashes with out of memory error.

Again, my main question is why the amount of free memory is so low right at the start of an application, before any processing is done.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Maybe you should add some code so we can see what is going on, or link to a github/bitbucket repo someone can look at? Also, are these apps doing the same thing on multiple devices, or on one specific device?  More details are needed here in order to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing such high amount of memory usage percentage is because the heap hasn't grown to its maximum size. This means that even though you see 98% of usage that refers to your current heap size and not the total amount that you can use.

At runtime, the heap grows dynamically as Dalvik VM needs more memory. It is common that you start with a relatively small heap and with each GC if needed Dalvik will request more memory.

Now for your `OutOfMemoryError` it can be a lot of things. I would suggest sampling your bitmap at runtime using the `BitmapFactory` class `inSampleSize`